# How to make restarting time in service become faster?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-manifest

I have created some services in my android application. I  put start_sticky in them, but if the task killer killed my application, my service is restarting but it takes a long time.. Does anyone know how to decrease the restarting time when a service is restarted? or make a service become not restarted even if the task killer killed an application? thanks.

Comment: How long is "a long time"?  How does it compare to the time taken to start the application normally?

Comment: it takes about 1 minute for restarting that service.. and about 2 second for open that application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it takes about 1 minute for restarting that service.. and about 2 second for open that application..

That's a *big* difference.

I don't know what the answer is, but you may be able to track the cause of the slowness down by profiling.

Comment: yup stephen.. i still don't know why restarting a service takes longer time than start a new service.. btw, thanks for your advice.. :)